# Rails 3: How to render an action from another controller's view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action, render

I'm trying to call an action from a different controller's view:

Controller `Countries` has an action called `selectbox` which generates a html selectbox from all countries as a partial.
Controller `Customers` has an action called `new` which generates a html form for all the customers attributes. I want to insert the selectbox from `Countries#selectbox` in this form.

What would be the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you are doing, extracting the code into helper method is the right way to do it. However, if you still want to use am action from another, this is the official Rails plugin you can use:

https://github.com/rails/render_component

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong. If there's a piece of code that is to be reused (such as html selectbox generation), you should put it in a helper and/or use a partial to render the html selectbox part.

Bear in mind this is only good advice if the code is somewhat complex (say, more than one or two lines). Here's a post I found while googling that may help you: [helper or partial](http://emeryfinkelstein.ca/web-design/refactoring-views-in-rails-helpers-or-partials/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've decided to leave my code in the partial. But there's another problem: I want to reuse the selectbox via AJAX and so the partial belongs to the controller 'Countries'. Is there a way to call an action from within a view from another controller?

Comment: @silent check out a gem called 'cells', or google for ' rails cells'